# Very long SQL Query, can it be optimized

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a very long SQL query which has a standard format

```
select * 
  from salary 
 where employe_id = 101 
    OR employe_id = 102 
    OR employe_id = 103 
    OR employe_id = 104 
    OR employe_id = 105 
........................ repeated 1000's of times.
```

My issue is that a sql query has a max length. And that can be a bottleneck in my design.

My questions are,

> is there a way to optimize this query to say something like `where employe_id = 101, 102, 103`.

OR Even better

> is there a way to optimize this query into say something like `where employe_id = <a csv file>`.

I need to make it `limitless`.

Comment: where employe_id in (101, 102, ... 1000)

Comment: where employe_id between 101 and 1000

Comment: Store the query ids and then join them

Comment: As said above - change to `where employe_id IN (101,102...)`. But it is also good idea to change your design. Or at lease move 101,102...1000 in separate table and do `where employe_id IN (SELECT id FROM id_list)`.

Comment: Switching to IN() will do nothing for optimisation - other than perhaps get around the query length problem.

Comment: Why are you building a huge set of IDs? Isn't there any other way to filter the employee set other than specifying each ID individually?  E.G date range, office location, salary etc...

Comment: I am hoping to get superior performance by using ID's since they are all indexed.

Comment: @strawberry You said in your own answer how this helps optimization.  No the code does not necessarily run any faster, but there is less of it doing the same job.  Also between will only work if he first sorts the data or otherwise knows the range.  There is nothing in his question that indicates he knows the range or that the data is sorted.

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to do it:

```
select * from salary where employee_id IN(101, 102 ... 105); 
select * from salary where employee_id BETWEEN 101 AND 105;
select * from salary where employee_id >= 101 AND  employee_id <= 105;
```

Comment: I upvoted this, as I like the array of answers, but please bear in mind that the OP never indicated he knew the min and max values.  Therefore, for his exact question, only the top option would work.

Comment: he did not mention that he doesn't know them as well :P but thanks for suggestion

Comment: Ha! Point taken.  This is why I upvoted your answer.  While the first one is the only one that actually fits his question, without the sin of omission you mentioned, the bottom two are the ones one would WANT to use in this situation, for maximum efficiency.

Comment: ***@Robert***: When `min` and `max` are *not known* to use with `between` we can also use like `between least(list of values) and greatest(lov)` and similarly wherever possible.

Comment: I thought about it but it would be long to write solution and query has its length limit

Answer (score 2):

I think you would have to use an external application to use a csv file.

To make the query more efficient, use the "in" keyword.

```
    Where employee_id in (1000,1001,1002, ....)
```

EDIT:  Also BETWEEN will only work if you first sort the data or otherwise know the range.  There is nothing in your question that indicates you know the range or that the data is sorted.  Therefore, your best case is to use IN.

You could either loop through an external file using the programming language of your choice or import the IDs to a separate table and populate the query from there with a sub query.

Comment: This won't aid effiiciency

Comment: There are different measures of efficiency.  While the code might not run any faster, he is typing less of it to get the same result.  Ergo, more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can go a couple of routes, but the basic ideas are as follows:

- Include the Ids you want to filter by in a `WHERE` predicate.  You can use the `IN` or `BETWEEN` operators.

  ```
  SELECT * FROM Salary WHERE EmployeeID in (101, 102, ..., 1000)

  SELECT * FROM Salary WHERE EmployeeID BETWEEN 101 and 1000
  ```
- Create a table from a CSV or other input and join to it.  This can be accomplished with a temporary object (Temp Table, `CTE` or Table Valued Function).  Or you can load the file to a disk-based object, like `dbo.EmployeeIDFromCSV`.  This can be done with a `BULK INSERT` statement or SSIS package.